# Server-Client Errno[10061] VM = server, Hostmachine = Client / UPDATE Errno[10060]

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, server, client, ubuntu-16.04

So i've been working on trying to pass messages from my Virtual machine (server) to my host machine (client) I've noticed that I was able to get my server to listen I'm listening on IP: 127.0.1.1 : port 1234.

The server is running this code, which didn't give me any compiling errors
Again the server is run on my Virtual Machine (Ubuntu16_04).

Server_Script

```
import socket
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 1234
address=(ip,port)
server.bind(address)
server.listen(1)
print "[*] Started listening on ",ip,":",port
client.addr= server.accept()
print "[*] Got a connection from ",addr[0],":",addr[1]
while True:
    data = client.recv(1024)
    print "[*] Received '",data,"' from the client"
    print "     Processing data"
    if(data--"Hello server"):
        client.send("Hello client")
        print " Processing done. \n[*] Reply sent"
    elif(data=="disconnect"):
        client.send("Goodbye")
        client.close()
        break
    else:
        client.send("Invalid data")
        print " Processing done, Invalid data. \n[*] Reply sent"
```

But as I attempt to connect to the server via my Host-machine I get this error

```
> >>> import socket
>>> client=socket.socket()
>>> client.connect(('127.0.1.1',1234))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

This is the error i'm receiving from windows powershell on my host computer which is the **CLIENT**

My firewall on my computer is shut off completely, and I just went through this tutorial on trying to setup a static ip to see if I could get my system to communicate but nothing is really budging

**[https://serverfault.com/questions/225155/virtualbox-how-to-set-up-networking-so-both-host-and-guest-can-access-internet][1]**

I've also used this for port forwarding issues, thought this might have something to do with it but still no luck (Note that I used the exact static IP address as the guide basically did the processes step by step before reattempting to connect the computers via socket.)

**[https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/][1]**

If anyone has any idea on what I can do to get this darn connection to work I would greatly appreciate it!

This is the code that I was using that was giving me an error message through powershell "python 2.7.14"

I've tried the IP that is given from the script, I tried the IP that were given on setting up a static IP

And lastly, I'm sure this will be asked for at some point so I'll put it in here, this is basically the ifconfig of my VM that I want as the server

```
 enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:74:4c:f0  
          inet addr:192.168.56.56  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c378:fdbb:a955:5826/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:134 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5620 (5.6 KB)  TX bytes:14439 (14.4 KB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:42:79:85  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:123 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:640 (640.0 B)  TX bytes:20585 (20.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19341 (19.3 KB)  TX bytes:19341 (19.3 KB)
```

------------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------------------

I have modified the original server code to not be bound to localhost (as advised), as well as attempt to connect to the server via the proper IP, I have now come across a different error code, any suggestions on what I may be screwing up on! :)

```
client.connect(('192.168.56.56',1234))

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because
 connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: `127.0.1.1` is always "this host". You need to use a non-localhost address (i.e. `192.168.56.56`)

Comment: Also, you don't want your server to bind to localhost, otherwise outside machines won't be able to connect. Use `0.0.0.0` for "any host".

Comment: I went ahead and modified the tuple to have '0.0.0.0' verses ip, and used the 192.168.56.56 to connect, now im receiving a different error [Errno 10060]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### server

```
import socket
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = ''
port = 1234
address=(ip,port)
server.bind(address)
server.listen(1)
print "[*] Started listening on ",ip,":",port
n = 0
while n < 1:
    client.addr= server.accept()
    n += 1
    print "[*] Got a connection from ",addr[0],":",addr[1]
    ## stuff
```